# Unable to SSH to Cisco Router

Tags: networking, ssh, cisco

SSHing to my Cisco Router ends up hanging indefinitely.

When attempting to ssh -vvv from Ubuntu to my Cisco router (IOS 15.8) with the SSH command, It says `Connection established.`. While directly connected to the router via console, I can see:

```
Router#SH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.10
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

So my SSH client sent something, but I'm not sure if this particular thing sent is intended.
I can also see a reflection of my console through the SSH client as I update it directly from the console,
e.g. If I send `Router>enable` to my router directly through the console I will see `debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: Router>enable` on my SSH client. [Image of connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wt57F.png).

Here is my config:

```
username cisco password 0 cisco
line vty 0 4
 password cisco
 login local
 transport input ssh
```

I've also already generated my RSA keys on the router.

Some information that may or may not be part of the problem:

1. I'm using eve-ng.
2. Telnetting works.
3. Attempting to SSH through paramiko results in: `Error reading ssh protocol banner'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0` while I've already configured banner_timeout.